# Problem generating code with ANTLR 1.3 / ANTLRWorks

Tags: antlr, antlrworks

I have downloaded ANTLR 1.3 and ANTLRWorks and can generate rules and syntax diagrams OK. When I try to generate code (e.g. by GenerateCode in ANTLRWorks or with `java org.antlr.Tool Temp.g` I get

```
error(100): C:\temp\Temp.g 0:0: syntax error: codegen: <AST>: 0:0: unexpected end of subtree
```

I'm on Windows 7 beta, Java 1.6. I have not specifically set up a classpath as the distro implied ANTLRWorks worked out of the box.

**EDIT**
This is a trivial grammar (generated by ANTLRWorks example) and yes, the file exists, with contents:

```
grammar Temp;

ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
    ;
```

Comment: Does this happen with a trivial grammar?

Comment: Does the file c:\temp\Temp.g exist?  The error is one that you can get if you are passed an empty file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because there were only lexical rules (of the type above). When I included:

```
prog: ID;
```

it worked